# Partitioning of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

This is a previous exam question.

Let $S$ be a subset of $\{10,11,...,99\}$ containing 10 elements. Show that there will exist two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $S$ such that sum of the elements of $A$ is same as that of $B$?

A few years ago, I had solved a similar problem but on counting. Here I have no clue where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of elements of $S$ can be at most $90+91+\cdots+99 = 945$. Hence, any subset of $S$ can only have the sum of their elements vary from $10$ to $945$ and there are $2^{10}-2$ non-trivial subsets. Use pigeonhole principle and obtain the two sets. To ensure that the sets are disjoint, remove the elements in the intersection and the sum remains the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had totally forgot to use the pigeon hole principle.